# Create a Firebase Sign In function with completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, completionhandler

I would like to have global `func signIn` that I can use inside my app but my problem is that I need to call some `functions` after the user is created. I thought I could use a `completion handler` for that but I tried it like this which gives me an error:

```
static func signIn(credentials: Any?, username: String, finished: () -> Void){
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials as! AuthCredential, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler bei Kontoerstellung", description: error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            //user was created successfully; store name, username and UID
            let db = Firestore.firestore()

            let userID = user!.user.uid

            db.collection("users").document(userID).setData(["username": username, "uid": user!.user.uid]) { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            // generate empty "Main Wishlist"
            db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document("Main Wishlist").setData(["name": "Main Wishlist", "listIDX": 1]) { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }

            // set user status to logged-in
            UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            finished()

        }
    })
}
```

**Error:**

> Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'finished'

Before the change my `function` looked like this:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler bei Kontoerstellung", description: error!.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        //user was created successfully; store name, username and UID
                        let db = Firestore.firestore()

                        let userID = user!.user.uid

                        db.collection("users").document(userID).setData(["username": username, "uid": user!.user.uid]) { (error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: error!.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                        // generate empty "Main Wishlist"
                        db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document("Main Wishlist").setData(["name": "Main Wishlist", "listIDX": 1]) { (error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: error!.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }

                        // set user status to logged-in
                        UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                        // stop animation
                        self.logoAnimation.stop()

                        //transition to home
                        self.transitionToHome()
                    }
                })
            }
```

As you can see in this example I am calling `self.logoAnimation.stop()` and `self.transitionToHome()`.

How can I outclass the method but still call methods when the user is signed up?

If anything is unclear just let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I added the batch write.

```
static func signIn(credentials: Any?, username: String, finished: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {

    guard let credentials = credentials as? AuthCredential else {

        finished(false)
        return

    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (result, error) in

        if let userId = result?.user.uid { // successfully signed in

            let batch = Firestore.firestore().batch()

            batch.setData(["username": username, "uid": userId], forDocument: Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userId), merge: true)
            batch.setData(["name": "Main Wishlist", "listIDX": 1], forDocument: Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userId).collection("wishlists").document("Main Wishlist"), merge: true)

            batch.commit { (error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    // maybe sign user out and on completion call finished(false)
                    // whatever you do, you must call finished(false) at some point
                } else {

                    UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                    finished(true) // sign-in process complete

                }

            }

        } else { // could not sign in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            finished(false)

        }

    })

}
```

The call to this method would look like this:

```
signIn(credentials: credentials, username: someString, finished: { (done) in

    if done { // success
        ...
    } else { // failure
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! About the `transaction`; I thought they are used when reading and writing new data but here I simply want to create the user and set the standart values that all users have.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, sometimes I use the term transaction generically. You're right, I meant to say batch write. Batch writes are the other atomic Firestore operation.

Comment: alright, never used Batch writes before but it seems like it would make sense in my case. But I would still use your structure form the answer right?

Comment: @Chris I included the batch write in the answer.

Comment: is `dispatch` no longer need with `batch` ? I tried it with it and it seems to be working fine. And one more thing, you are using `merge`  in `setData` . Is this actually necessary ? btw, really appreciate your help man !

Comment: @Chris Dispatching is only needed for multiple async operations but the batch write is a single async operation. In my original answer, we performed 2 separate writes to the database which produced 2 separate async returns. All the dispatch does is keep a record of how many times we enter it (we enter it before the write) and leave it (we leave it after the write finishes) and when they match up (entered twice, left twice), it calls the `notify` method which is its completion handler.

Comment: @Chris `setData` without merge will overwrite the entire document with the data you give it. `setData` with merge will integrate the data with the document (and keep the other fields in the document). If the document doesn't exist, `setData` (with or without merge) will create the document. `updateData` on the other hand will fail if the document doesn't exist. If you know the document exists, `updateData` is the way to go. If there's a possibility the document may not exist, `setData` is the way to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210119/discussion-between-chris-and-bsod).